# Struts2-Jquery Grid CSS Editing

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

I have a [Struts2-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag) Grid component on my webpage.

It works perfectly, but how can I edit the CSS rules for the Struts2-jQuery-Grid plugin ?

Can I apply my custom CSS rules to this grid view ?

Comment: you need to specify your question

Comment: is there any way to change css properties with out using default themes?

Comment: sure, again, you should specify your question, otherwise I cannot help you

Comment: if you want to change the entire styles of the grid, i will suggest you to define your customized theme

Comment: How can i create a new jquery theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`To answer your question: how to create a new jquery theme?`

1. Just like @Andrea mentioned, You should use [jQuery ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)
2. Define your `sj:head` like this

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
   <html>
     <head>
       <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="mytheme" 
                customBasepath="template/themes"/>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. You should care following style classes.

   - ui-widget-header
   - ui-state-default
   - ui-widget-content

If you want to adjust single style, you can use either CSS selector or jQuery selector to do this.

the plugin will do the rest. Just try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default theme by using one of the other themes from `jQuery`, simply changing the import of the `jQuery CSS`.

You can see them in [`jQuery ThemeRoller`](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) (Gallery tab), and in the [`Struts2-jQuery Showcase`](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) too (using the themeroller combobox on top-right corner).

If none of them satisfies your needs,

just choose the theme closer to what you want, and define a `CSS` of your,

declaring it **AFTER** the jQuery `CSS` import (because order of import of `CSS`s matters, **the last win**),

and manually doing the override of every `style declaration` you need to change;

To easily and quickly see (and experiments with) them, you can use `FireBug` on `FireFox`, or similar tools on other browsers.

---

For example, if you use

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td{
    border-right-style: dashed;
}
```

in your `CSS`, you will have dashed borders for your `TD`s, no matter which theme are you using.

---

You could even create your personal `jQuery CSS Theme` from nothing, 
but I doubt this is what you are looking for, it wouldn't be a quick work...