# Overriding Struts 2 jqGrid CSS

Tags: css, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

I'm stuck on overriding the default's `struts2-jquery-plugin` stylesheet for a grid. I tried defining my own stylesheet (`jquery-ui-grid.css`) and including it on my JSP page but the framework always downloads the default CSS (`ui.jqgrid.css`) last and overrides my own styles.

I've used the Chrome developer tools to watch network requests so I could verify that both default CSS and my custom CSS are being downloaded, but only the default is applied (I guess because it's downloaded last). As this *default* CSS is generated by the Struts 2 framework, I have no idea how can I modify/override it as I don't know the path to this file.

I'm currently using Maven to manage my dependencies and the `struts2-jquery-plugin`  and `struts2-jqgrid-plugin` are being included from Maven.

I'm trying to change the font size for my grids and I'm getting a little bit desperate at this point...

How can I override/modify the default CSS file that the plugin is using to style the grids? I wouldn't like to change the styles applied to the HTML tables, I'm searching for a solution that allows me *specifically* modify the `jqGrid` related CSS classes.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15022896/3736964), I included my CSS after the `jquery-ui` ones (inside the `<head />`  tag):

```xml
<head>
...
<s:head />
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="south-street" loadAtOnce="true"  loadFromGoogle="false" locale="es"/>
<link href="<s:url value='/styles/main.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
...
</head>
```

And inside my `main.css` belong all the CSS imports:

```css
/*
   Css Framework 
   =============
     - see http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/Articles/17/a-css-framework
       for more info.
*/
@import url("tools.css");
@import url("typo.css");
@import url("forms.css");
@import url("layout.css");
/* This is my "custom" jqGrid stylesheet: */
@import url("ui.jqgrid.css");
@import url("dl-forms.css");
```

---

**PROGRESS UPDATE:**

I still hadn't been able to override as I wanted to, so for now I had to stop using a `jquery-ui` theme served from the internet (I prefer that way so I can keep it updated on the fly, as there is no need for major tweaks on the jQuery UI CSS for my webapp).
I downloaded the theme I'm using and put it inside my webapp (`template/themes/myTheme-name/`), so I could force the framework to use that explicit theme instead of downloading it, and that indeed worked, I can now modify my *custom* CSS for jqGrid. But I feel like this is just a workaround and I would like to know how to do it the clean way.

Answer (score 0):

These are steps to create/modify a [custom theme](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag#custom-themes):

> Create and Download your own Theme with [jQuery ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)
>
> 1. Create a folder in your `WebRoot` path `template/themes/mytheme`
> 2. Extract downloaded theme and switch into the css folder
> 3. Rename `jquery-ui-x.x.x.custom.css` to `jquery-ui.css`
> 4. Copy `jquery-ui.css` and images folder into the `template/themes/mytheme` folder.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
> <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> 
> <html>   
>    <head>
>     <s:url var="context" value="/" />
>     <sj:head locale="de" jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="mytheme" customBasepath="%{context}template/themes"/>   
>    </head>
>    <body>  
>    </body> 
> </html>
> ```

You can also play with `scriptPath` attribute where you can place your JS code. The same way as you doing it with CSS but copying into `js` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Roman . This solution is the one I used and updated on my question, but as I describe on my progress update, doing it this way implies downloading the theme from the `ThemeRoller` and having it stored on my webapp (and I would like to keep downloading it from the jQuery ui server every when needed so I can have it always updated). I hope there is another solution which allows me to **only** store and modify `jqGrid`  styles in my webapp..