# Struts 2 jquery plugin, chart plugin does not support categories

Tags: jquery, struts2, flot, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-chart

The chart component in the Struts 2 jQuery plugin version 3.6 seems not supporting the `category` plugin for the `sjc:chart`.

I want to use `Flot With “String” x-axis` for chart and the best solution is to use `jquery.flot.categories.js` (Described at [Flot With "String" x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820954/flot-with-string-x-axis)).

As I reviewed some `struts-jquery-plugin` code, I found that the `jquery.chart.struts2.js` does not use this plugin, on the other hand the `jquery.flot.categories.js` file is in the `struts2-jquery-chart-plugin-3.7.1.jar` file.

Please let me know how can I fix it ?! I think I can extend the used jquery objects ( may be `$.struts2_jquery_chart` ) and add it but don't know how ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easily fixable, just modify your `jquery.chart.struts2.js` and add the following code.

```js
if ((o.xaxis && o.xaxis.mode === "categories") || (o.yaxis && o.yaxis.mode === "categories")) {
    self.require("js/flot/jquery.flot.categories" + self.minSuffix + ".js");
}
```

If you like to know how to use custom theme with Struts2 jQuery plugin, you should read [Overriding Struts2 jqGrid CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155445/573032).

**References:**

- [Struts2 jQuery Plugin 3.4.0 with improved Chart Tag released](http://www.jgeppert.com/2012/10/struts2-jquery-plugin-3-4-0-with-improved-chart-tag-released/)
- [ChartTag](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/ChartTag)
- [Categories](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html)

Comment: This also worked `jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/flot/jquery.flot.categories"+jQuery.struts2_jquery.minSuffix+".js");` for me